# angular ui router blank page with query string params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string, angular-ui-router

I've been dealing with this query string param issue for a long time, that if go to `/` everything works ok but if try something like `/?anything` it just won't work,these are my two states each one of them in it's own file.

```
var access = accessConfig.accessLevels;
$stateProvider.state('store', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'store/main.html',
  data: {
    access: access.user
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('store.home', {
  url: '/?cart',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'store/home/home.html',
      controller: 'store.home as vm'
    }
  },
  data: {
    title: 'Home'
  }
});
```

Whenever I go to `/` I get the expected results with no issues but if I try to go to `/?cart` or `/?anything` I get a blank page, I have a `stateChangeStart` event that is called anytime I go to `/` but when I go to `/?anything` the event is not even fired.

I'm using `html5mode(true)` by the way, any clues on what's going on?

it works if using `ui-sref` but not if copying/pasting urls directly in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/15xQ1JE9F0uAYtrTwB6R?p=preview). It shows, that this scenario and state definition is correct.

We just have to be sure, that the **`cart`** parameter is provided with value. These examples will work, because we pass cart param:

```
<a ui-sref="store.home({cart:458})">
<a ui-sref="store.home({cart:'xyz'})">
```

Because `plunker` environment requires some **`<base href=""`**  to be provided, I also make it working there with `href`:

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl" >
  <a href="{{path}}?cart=abc">
  <a href="{{path}}?cart=123">
  ...
```

where the `path` is:

```
.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.path = document.location.pathname;
}])
```

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/15xQ1JE9F0uAYtrTwB6R?p=preview), with **html5Mode enabled**

EXTEND

To show that this is working even when we want to pass params via address bar, I created a special plunker here

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/syVPqrhNZpQJDdcCxx9b/?cart=myTestParam

as we can see, it passes the param **`/?cart=myTestParam`** and we can see that in this template: `<pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>`:

```
{
  "cart": "myTestParam"
}
```

You can observe its code here

http://plnkr.co/edit/syVPqrhNZpQJDdcCxx9b?p=catalogue

Important part in the code is the `<head>` section and the element base

with proper setting of the html5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: true});
```

Comment: thanks Radim, I forgot to say that it works using links, but not using direct access like typing, copy/paste '/?cart=open' and then hit enter.

Comment: @Gustavo, I created a version of my plunker for you, with a direct access to address bar. You can type whatever param you like to see how that stuff is working in action. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Radim, I see your code works perfectly but mine doesn't, it's probably something else.